# Get CSS link in blogger

Tags: blogger

Recently I changed my blogger template. I was doing normal page load test and all. I found one stylesheet loading in page is heavy. I checked in my template but its not linked in it. So how its loading in page?

Blog URL: [www.javaquery.com](http://www.javaquery.com)

```
<link href="https://googledrive.com/host/0B6P5jmo5InDtVllmUF9zV3dwems" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

I'm completely clueless don't know whats going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These CSS file is being added by an obfuscated javascript present in the template

The JavaScript in question

```
   <script type='text/javascript'>
          //<![CDATA[
          var _0x242d=["\x3C\x6C\x69\x6E\x6B\x20\x68\x72\x65\x66\x3D\x27\x68\x74\x74\x70\x73\x3A\x2F\x2F\x67\x6F\x6F\x67\x6C\x65\x64\x72\x69\x76\x65\x2E\x63\x6F\x6D\x2F\x68\x6F\x73\x74\x2F\x30\x42\x36\x50\x35\x6A\x6D\x6F\x35\x49\x6E\x44\x74\x56\x6C\x6C\x6D\x55\x46\x39\x7A\x56\x33\x64\x77\x65\x6D\x73\x27\x20\x72\x65\x6C\x3D\x27\x73\x74\x79\x6C\x65\x73\x68\x65\x65\x74\x27\x20\x74\x79\x70\x65\x3D\x27\x74\x65\x78\x74\x2F\x63\x73\x73\x27\x2F\x3E","\x77\x72\x69\x74\x65"];document[_0x242d[1]](_0x242d[0]);
          //]]></script>
```

Tool used to test http://jsunpack.jeek.org/